# Information about the processor using the pidin command

Tags: qnx

Good afternoon. Is it possible to use the pidin command to get data only about the processor model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pidin info` is hardcoded to a fixed output format; you could write a brief script to pipe it through any of the usual POSIX text manipulation tools such as `awk` to extract the portion you want.

Alternately, you could write a program to access the same information directly from the system page and format it yourself.  See the [SYSPAGE_ENTRY() macro](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/s/syspage_entry.html) and [the cpuinfo page documentation](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.building/topic/syspage/cpuinfo.html) for details on what's available for programs to read there.  The startup library stores a friendly CPU name in the `cpuinfo.name` element, which can be accessed like so:

```
#include <sys/syspage.h>

const char* get_cpu0_name() {
    struct cpuinfo_entry* cpu = SYSPAGE_ENTRY(cpuinfo);
    return &SYSPAGE_ENTRY(strings)->data[cpu->name];
}
```